# Counting events by day while respecting timezone in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone

I have a very large table in a postgres database. It has a timestamp column, and I want to count the number of rows "per day" over a time period. It's easy enough to do this naïvely by `GROUP BY`ing the output of `date_trunc` on the timestamp column. However, this does not account for the timezone of the user (I want to group by days such that midnight for the user is *their* midnight, not UTC midnight.

I've accomplished this by manually adjusting the timestamp by adding an interval representing the time zone offset of the user before truncating it. This works, but it's slow and results in the indexes I've set up not being used.

Is there a better way to accomplish this that's better-supported by Postgres?

Comment: How is the data being stored?  `date_trunc()` is what you want, if you are storing the value as `timestamp with timezone`.

Comment: Time zone is not being stored. All timestamps are in UTC.

Comment: . . Well, the data is broken.  It should be using `timestamp with time zone` if you care about the timezone.  How do you know what timezone your users are in?

Comment: Please show: Postgres version, table definition, index definition, sample data, query (even if it's not working).

Comment: Gordon: the data is time zone agnostic. I only know what timezone the user is in when they make the request. The request to my application server includes their timezone offset at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what timezone the values are in, you can switch time zones:

```
select date_trunc('day', col at time zone 'American/New_York')
```

Comment: This seems to be equivalent to what I described I'm doing now (adding the time zone offset as an interval before truncating the timestamp). Does it carry some sort of efficiency improvement over my approach?